# validation of constraints in oracle

Tags: oracle, validation, testing, constraints, etl

I am new to oracle and I would like to know how do we validate constraints in oracle tables as part of the ETL testing process. (The two tables could be T1 and T2). Please let me know a sample query.

Thanks, Santosh

Comment: the way I would validate a constraint it to try to load records that violate the constraints

Comment: if you want to see if a constraint would work, after the fact, do a select WHERE and add your check constraint logic to the predicate - if you get any results, you'll need to clean your data before you create/enable the constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of the options you have

```
SQL> create table t1 as select distinct owner from dba_objects;

Table created.

SQL> alter table t1 add primary key ( owner );

Table altered.

SQL> create table t2 as select * from dba_objects;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> update t2 set owner = 'BAD_DATA' where rownum <= 10;

10 rows updated.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

So we want to link OWNER between T1 and T2, and T2 has some bad data.  Adding a constraint gives an error

```
SQL>
SQL> alter table t2 add constraint fk foreign key ( owner ) references t1 ( owner );
alter table t2 add constraint fk foreign key ( owner ) references t1 ( owner )
                              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02298: cannot validate (MCDONAC.FK) - parent keys not found
```

So the first thing I'll do is enable it in NOVALIDATE mode which means no *more* bad data can come in

```
SQL>
SQL>
SQL>
SQL> alter table t2 add constraint fk foreign key ( owner ) references t1 ( owner ) enable novalidate;

Table altered.
```

Now once you've done that, you can then attempt to validate the constraint. (Obviously we know this will fail, but in the general case, you would enable novalidate, and then try enable validate.  That means less locking on your system)

```
SQL>
SQL> alter table t2 modify constraint fk enable validate;
alter table t2 modify constraint fk enable validate
                                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02298: cannot validate (MCDONAC.FK) - parent keys not found
```

If we want to see the actual bad data, then we can create a table called EXCEPTIONS with a predelivered script in $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin.

```
SQL> @?/rdbms/admin/utlexcpt.sql

Table created.
```

Now we can extend the validate command to capture the rows.  We still get the error

```
SQL>
SQL> alter table t2 modify constraint fk enable validate exceptions into exceptions;
alter table t2 modify constraint fk enable validate exceptions into exceptions
                                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02298: cannot validate (MCDONAC.FK) - parent keys not found
```

But now the bad rows have been captured into a table

```
SQL>
SQL> select * from exceptions;

ROW_ID             OWNER                TABLE_NAME CONSTRAINT
------------------ -------------------- ---------- --------------------
AAAySAAAHAAABhjAAA MCDONAC              T2         FK
AAAySAAAHAAABhjAAB MCDONAC              T2         FK
AAAySAAAHAAABhjAAC MCDONAC              T2         FK
AAAySAAAHAAABhjAAD MCDONAC              T2         FK
AAAySAAAHAAABhjAAE MCDONAC              T2         FK
AAAySAAAHAAABhjAAF MCDONAC              T2         FK
AAAySAAAHAAABhjAAG MCDONAC              T2         FK
AAAySAAAHAAABhjAAH MCDONAC              T2         FK
AAAySAAAHAAABhjAAI MCDONAC              T2         FK
AAAySAAAHAAABhjAAJ MCDONAC              T2         FK

10 rows selected.
```

If you want to run a simple query to check what rows are bad, an outer join where you want to get the rows that did NOT manage to join will do the trick as well.

```
SQL>
SQL> select t2.owner, t2.rowid
  2  from t1,
  3       t2
  4  where t2.owner = t1.owner(+)
  5  and t1.owner is null;

OWNER                ROWID
-------------------- ------------------
BAD_DATA             AAAySAAAHAAABhjAAA
BAD_DATA             AAAySAAAHAAABhjAAB
BAD_DATA             AAAySAAAHAAABhjAAC
BAD_DATA             AAAySAAAHAAABhjAAD
BAD_DATA             AAAySAAAHAAABhjAAE
BAD_DATA             AAAySAAAHAAABhjAAF
BAD_DATA             AAAySAAAHAAABhjAAG
BAD_DATA             AAAySAAAHAAABhjAAH
BAD_DATA             AAAySAAAHAAABhjAAI
BAD_DATA             AAAySAAAHAAABhjAAJ

10 rows selected.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL>
```